# Splitting maul handle cracked... is it still usable?

Tags: safety, hand-tools

I was splitting logs for firewood today, and must have swung wrong, because the outer shell of the fiberglass handle on my maul shattered.

[image: This is why I can't have nice things.]

Although the core of the handle appears intact, and the head isn't loose on the handle, I'm having second thoughts about further use.

Ludell had a lifetime warranty on it, but the company that acquired them isn't honoring said warranty.

What I want to know is, can I still (safely) use this maul, or is it pretty much landfill at this point?

Comment: @brock: How would I deal with the epoxy used to adhere the head to the handle? Solvents of some sort?

Comment: If they make a replacement handle, replace it ASAP.  Otherwise chuck it.  The head should come flying off once the shell finishes delaminating from the core -- which looks like it could be soon.

Comment: @BrockAdams I don't think the plastic goes through the entire head -- usually it ends at the bottom of the head, and the epoxy bonds the fiberglass to the metal, so even if the whole thing delaminates it will be fine.  I've broken several of these -- they rarely go flying; they tend to loosen gradually.

Comment: @gbronner, okay but if you've really broken several of those, you may be doing somethings wrong. :)

Comment: @BrockAdams  Took me a while to build accuracy, and I split a *lot* of wood that wasn't cut perfectly square -- happens if you overhit.  Or if you are hammering a wedge and hit it with the shaft....

Answer (score 2):

First of all, that is a splitting maul, not an axe.

Secondly, the handle consists of a tough layer of plastic over a core layer of fiberglass. The plastic cushions the fiberglass, and, more importantly, keeps your hands from getting nasty splinters.

Because the strength comes from the core fiberglass center piece, you can still use the maul, but I'd wrap the broken section with a few wraps of duct tape. It will eventually break (depending on how often you miss), but that could take years.

Should you want to remove it, the best way is to cut off the handle with a saw and then use a drill to drill out the epoxy, and get replacement handle kit. This is time consuming, hence my recommendation to use the handle until it actually breaks, as it often becomes easier to remove then.

Comment: Wait, I thought you said this was a splitting maul? You just called it an axe. It's a maul if you axe me : )